# What do Profiles do uniquely?

Tags: permissions, profile, permission-sets

After becoming frustrated with the half-dozen Profiles that all do the same thing (except for subtle differences here and there), I have started on cleaning up my org's permissions scheme.

My basic idea is to have as few Profiles as possible, and a separate Permission Set for each task a User may perform in their job.  This allows the organization to change position responsibilities flexibly, reduces my maintenance burden, and documents not only *who* has access to a thing, but *why* they have it.

I'm now fully bought into cutting out Profiles altogether, but I recognize that the platform isn't.  What is the full set of things that Profiles control that I can't alter in Permission Sets?

Comment: dupe: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/119297/7195

Answer (score 2):

To start, this is my list so far:

- The Default Case User must be on a Profile that has Can Modify All Data.
- Page Layouts Assignments
- Login restrictions
- Password policies
- Session settings
- A User's default Default Record Types (Users can optionally change their Default Record Types - this simply establishes their defaults).
- Any User who should be in a Delegated Group for administration must have View Setup and Configuration in their Profile. (? this may be permission settable)