# Is Single Sign-On Enabled - Profile and/or Permission Set

Tags: delegated-authentication

Is the `Is Single Sign-On Enabled` permission that's used with Delegated Authentication available on Profiles and/or Permission Sets?

I understand that Salesforce needs to be contacted in order to enable Delegated Authentication and for the `Is Single Sign-On Enabled` permission to even show up but I'd like to know if that can be set at the Permission Set and/or Profile level.

The documentation from Salesforce does not make this clear "Enable the “Is Single Sign-On Enabled” permission."

[Source 1](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sso.meta/sso/sso_delauthentication_configuring.htm), [Source 2](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sso_delauthentication_configuring.htm&type=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `IsSsoEnabled` is a profile permission. You can see it [in the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_profile.htm).

> IsSsoEnabled
>
> Type
>
> boolean
>
> Properties
>
> Defaulted on create, Filter, Group, Sort
>
> Description
>
> If true, users assigned to this profile can delegate username and password authentication to a corporate database instead of the user database.

Comment: I'm not finding it in the PermissionSet documentation (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_permissionset.htm?search_text=permissionset) so I presume that this is only a permission for Profiles and not Permission Sets. Would you agree?

Comment: @John_Henry I'm pretty sure this is indeed one of the few things you can't assign via perm set.