# Difference between assigning permissions with a Profile vs Permission Set

Tags: profile, permission-sets

I have a custom application and one of our customers wants to use Profiles to manage the permissions to it instead of our existing Permission Set.

When I add all of the items from the Permission Set to the Profile I get

```
Content cannot be displayed: You do not have sufficient privileges to access the page: [name of page]
```

I just discovered today that in order for some of our Apex classes to be visible to the Profile I needed to declare the `global` instead of public. I assume I'm missing some other gotcha related to the page. Any ideas?

Comment: There's a separate permission for each page and a UI to multi-select them. Hard to advise what you missed though when you give little detail about what you actually did.

Comment: I didn't need to explicitly give permission to that page from the Permission Set, and even after throwing everything in the Profile (all classes and pages) I still can't see the page (permission error goes away but t's just blank). If I add the permission set everything works, but only things in the permission set are Classes and Pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no much of differences between Profile and Permission Set ([you can find them discussed here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/119220)), and I believe the preferable way for you would be to use Permission Set.

You do not have to assign permissions for Apex classes called from the page's controller(s) - access is provided automatically once you get the Page enabled.
In regard to the issue you are experiencing - check if the user get access to the SObjects referenced in the code.

Comment: It was indeed SObject permissions. I think I missed these because in the Profile all of our package specific objects are grouped together, but in the Permission Set My confusion came from they were mixed with standard objects and weren't marked with our namespace.

I was also able to leave out permissions to Apex Classes as those are never called directly thereby simplifying our permissions.

Comment: Also, I still find it odd that after giving permissions to one Visual Force Page I got a permission error referencing a sub-page because I didn't have permission to an SObject. Explicitly giving permission to the sub-page made the error go away (blank window). Once I granted the permission for the SObject I no longer needed permission to the sub-page.