# Consideration while creating new profile in Salesforce

Tags: salesforcedx

I need to create a new profile as the region is going to split. I need to make sure that wherever the existing profile is already considered this new profile is also added.
I'm not going to create a new profile by referencing this existing profile.
Is there any tool that might help as I need to go through all the objects and related workflow, approval process, validations? Doing this manual is going to take a lifetime and I need to do this as soon as possible. Any pointer will help me!
Thank you in advance.

Regards

Comment: Have you considered using [permission sets](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/119220/exclusive-differences-profiles-vs-permission-sets/119297)?

Comment: this tool [PermComparator](https://perm-comparator.herokuapp.com/) is handy

Comment: Thank you keith C and cropredy for you inputs as I'm able to get some ideas. But what I want is for example: consider ACCOUNT,LEAD,CONTACT and OPPORTUNITY OBJECTS; now, i want to know per OBJECT, all validation, workflows, approvals, process builders, flows, FLS works with an existing PROFILE or how it is reference and then I need to make sure that new PROFILE works exactly the same way. This way, due to region split NEW PROFILE users will continue to see what these users used to experience with OLD the PROFILE. All I thought of is complete manual way. Pointer to make the life easier